# RegEx To Find One or More Instances of 5 Consecutive Digits Within A Given Range

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am a newbie at RegEx, so I need some help.  Can anyone help me parse a string and find one or more instances of numbers that range from **40000** to **99999**?  Here are some example strings:

- Order Details, Acme, #46405,53000,86232, for 4/17 `- 3 instances`
- PSA Order Detail: Hiring Practices (46445); starting 4-16-12 `- 1 instance`
- PC Pitstop 32134 Direct for 4/18/12 `- 0 instances`

Comment: When asking regexp questions you should always tag it with the environment you will be using it in, since the syntax might differ.. Ex. java, php, grep, etc.

Comment: Thanks Barsju... it's for C# (so the .NET RegEx parser)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
(?<!\d)[4-9]\d{4}(?!\d)
```

See it on [regexr](http://regexr.com?30ndh)

**EDIT:** here is a `c#` code snippet to test it:

```
// could be whatever
var str = "50000 alpha 43 84100";
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<!\d)[4-9]\d{4}(?!\d)");
foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(str))
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
```

this outputs:

```
50000
84100
```

Comment: Thanks Alex.  I greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

You should use regex

```
(?<!\d)([4-9]\d{4})(?!\d)
```

---

**Untested** code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
  static void Main()
  {
    string input = "50000 Order Acme, #46405,53000,86232, for 4/17 60000";
    Regex t = new Regex(@"(?<!\d)([4-9]\d{4})(?!\d)", RegexOptions.Singleline) 
    MatchCollection theMatches = t.Matches(input) 
    for (int counter = 0; counter < theMatches.Count; counter++)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(theMatches[counter].Value); 
    }
  }
}
```

For multi-line input use `RegexOptions.Multiline` instead of `RegexOptions.Singleline`.

---

Note: *I suggest you always test regex with match at the begining and end of string.*

Comment: I've tested out (on RegExr, not through C# yet), and both your's and Alex's seem to work.   I'll test in my C# code next, but a quick question for you.  Your expression has a few more checks than Alex's (e.g. `(?:\A|(` before his).  What are these checking for?

Comment: @bmccleary - I just updated my answer - it was okay, but not necessary, as `\A` was optional begining of string and `\z` end of string. It would be needed if positive `(?<=) (?=)` lookaround is used, but we are using now negative lookaround `(?<!) (?!)`.

Comment: Thanks for all your help.  I wish I could mark both answers as correct, but since I can't and Alex posted the most correct answer first, I accepted his.  I do appreciate the input and advise though!

Comment: @bmccleary - Well, he just used mine and made it simplier, ... and then when I updated mine with code, he did later same with his - just copycat... but... your choice... I am disappointed.